# How can I aggregate based on min date but only after a dimension filter has been applied on all dates?

Tags: tableau-api

I’m trying to aggregate rows for the same ID based on their max date, but only within the current filter (I am filtering by date range). I know this has something to do with Level of Detail calculations (FIXED, INCLUDE) but I can’t quite get it.

The data looks like

```
ID: 1 | collection_date=2019-01-01
ID: 1 | collection_date=2020-02-01
ID: 1 | collection_date=2020-03-01
ID: 2 | collection_date=2018-01-01
ID: 2 | collection_date=2020-09-01
```

I am applying a dimension filter which only returns dates within the year `2020`.

If I try `{ FIXED [ID]:MIN([collection_date]) }` then the record for `2019-01-01` is returned as the MIN and no records are returned for the final view.

The `FIXED` selects the `2019-01-01` filter before the dimension filter attempts to select only things from 2020 and comes up empty.

My expected output is all records which have the max date within the range for their `ID`

```
ID: 1 | collection_date=2020-02-01
ID: 2 | collection_date=2020-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct use case of LOD statements. The LOD statements are meant to override the filters built in the context.

You simply can use date as measure instead of tableau default dimension. Do it like this
Drag date desired view (rows or columns).  Right click -> convert to measure then select your measure as `Min`.  Now you want to create filters on the same field.  But this time you need this filter as dimension.
It should solve your problem. Else do tell me.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by changing the filter to a "context" filter by right clicking the blue filter pill and selecting "add to context" -- this way the data is filtered before any LOD expression is applied. I then used `{ FIXED [ID]:MIN([collection_date]) }` and achieved the correct results

Comment: @jcallin, Yes! the problem will solve that way also.  All I was saying that you have created an LOD field, which is redundant and not required given the functionality of tableau to aggregate dates.  In that case, your simple filter would've worked too.  Nevertheless, you got your solution.